# Opening a file of varying row and column structure in Scilab

Tags: csv, range, scilab

I habitually use csvRead in scilab to read my data files however I am now faced with one which contains blocks of 200 rows, preceeded by 3 lines of headers, all of which I would like to take into account.

I've tried specifying a range of data following the example on the scilab help website for csvRead (example is right at the bottom of the page) (https://help.scilab.org/doc/6.0.0/en_US/csvRead.html) but I always come out with the same error messages :

`The line and/or colmun indices are outside of the limits`

or

`Error in the column structure.`

My first three lines are headers which I know can cause a problem but even if I omit them from my block-range, I still have the same problem.

Otherwise, my data is ordered such that I have my three lines of headers (two lines containing a header over just one or two columns, one line containing a header over all columns), 200 lines of data, and a blank line - this represents data from one image and I have about 500 images in the file, I would like to be able to read and process all of them and keep track of the headers because they state the image number which I need to reference later. Example:

```
DTN-dist_Devissage-1_0006_0,,,,,,
L0,,,,,,
X [mm],Y [mm],W [mm],exx [1] - Lagrange,eyy [1] - Lagrange,exy [1] - Lagrange,Von Mises Strain [1] - Lagrange
-1.13307,-15.0362,-0.00137507,7.74679e-05,8.30045e-05,5.68249e-05,0.00012711
-1.10417,-14.9504,-0.00193334,7.66086e-05,8.02914e-05,5.43132e-05,0.000122655
-1.07528,-14.8647,-0.00249155,7.57493e-05,7.75786e-05,5.18017e-05,0.0001182
```

Does anyone have a solution to this?

My current code, following an adapted version of the Scilab-help example looks like this (I have tried varying the blocksize and iblock values to include/omit headers:

```
blocksize=200;
C1=1;
C2=14;
iblock=1
while (%t)
    R1=(iblock-1)*blocksize+4;
    R2=blocksize+R1-1;
    irange=[R1 C1 R2 C2];
    V=csvRead(filepath+filename,",",".","",[],"",irange);
   iblock=iblock+1
end
```

Comment: Could you provide a MWE ? your scilab code refers to a csv file that contains 200 lines of data, when your piece of example contains only 3. Either lower blocksize accordingly or provide your whole file.

Comment: Also your code states ',' as a separator when your .csv doesn't contain any.

Comment: Yep, so I actually copied the data from Excel where i'd already converted it to make it more readable hence why the comma separators had disappeared.

Comment: I've made a copy of the data file with just two blocks in it which should represent the problem all the same,
It can be downloaded here: https://dl.univ-lyon1.fr/o7w6b99o

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Errors

#### The CSV

A lot's of your problem comes from the inconsistency of the number of coma in your csv file. Opening it in `LibreOffice Calc` and saving it puts the right number of comma, even on empty lines.

#### R1

Your current code doesn't position R1 at the beginning of the values. The right formula is

```
R1=(iblock-1)*(blocksize+blanksize+headersize)+1+headersize;
```

#### End of file

Currently your code raise an error and the end of the file because R1 becomes greater than the number of lines. To solve this, you can specify the maximum number of block or test the value of R1 against the number of lines.

## Improved solution for much bigger file.

When solving your probem with a big file, two problems were raised :

1. We need to know the number of blocks or the number of lines
2. Each call of `csvRead` is really slow because it process the whole file at each call (1s / block !)

My idea was to read the whole file and store it in a string matrix ( since `mgetl` as been improved since 6.0.0 ), then use `csvTextScan` on a submatrix. Doing so also removes the manual writing of the number of block/lines.

The code follows :

```
clear all
clc

s = filesep()
filepath='.'+s;
filename='DTN_full.csv';

// header is important as it as the image name
headersize=3;
blocksize=200;
C1=1;
C2=14;
iblock=1

// let save everything. Good for the example.
bigstruct = struct();

// Read all the value in one pass
// then using csvTextScan is much more efficient
text = mgetl(filepath+filename);

nlines = size(text,'r');
while ( %t )
  mprintf("Block #%d",iblock);
  // Lets read the header
  R1=(iblock-1)*(headersize+blocksize+1)+1;
  R2=R1 + headersize-1;
  // if R1 or R1 is bigger than the number of lines, stop
  if sum([R1,R2] > nlines )
      mprintf('; End of file\n')
      break
  end
  // We use csvTextScan ony on the lines that matters
  // speed the program, since csvRead read thge whole file
  // every time it is used.
  H=csvTextScan(text(R1:R2),",",".","string");
  mprintf("; %s",H(1,1))

  R1 = R1 + headersize;
  R2 = R1 + blocksize-1;

  if sum([R1,R2]> nlines )
      mprintf('; End of file\n')
      break
  end
  mprintf("; rows %d to %d\n",R1,R2)
  // Lets read the values
  V=csvTextScan(text(R1:R2),",",".","double");

  iblock=iblock+1
  // Let save theses data
  bigstruct(H(1,1)) = V;
end
```

and returns

```
Block #1; DTN-dist_0005_0; rows 4 to 203

....
Block #178; DTN-dist_0710_0; rows 36112 to 36311
Block #179; End of file
Time elapsed 1.827092s
```

Comment: Thank you, first of all for this suggestion! While I don't doubt that it works, because when I look through it I can see the logic behind what you did, when I apply it to a bigger matrix (let's say number of blocks, nblock = 50), Scilab comes back with the same error message 
"Impossible to read file. Error in column structure"
I'm going to look into it further and also reinvestigate the different ways in which i can export my data to avoid such .csv file constructs

Comment: Provide the whole file. This example works with your file, which has only two blocks.

Comment: Here we go : 
Some info about this file : it has 14 columns (or 2x7) relating to two times the same variables but for different areas of what I was analysing. And the nblock comes much larger as well
https://dl.univ-lyon1.fr/gfhkzxdnvk

Comment: For info, for the file I just uploaded, I ran resaved it through LibreOffice Calc (good shout, thank you) and Scilab can now read the file. 
Nonetheless, my V matrix at the end is a 200x14 matrix consisting solely of NaN

Comment: Updated answer : optimized and improved. No more need for nblock.